# OpenGL benchmark

Tags: video, benchmarking, opengl, gpu

I'm working on an OpenGL based software library and I'd like to benchmark the gains/losses of some patches and modifications I did to it: the library works but I need to know whether it is faster or slower for an OpenGL application.

Could you recommend any OpenGL benchmark suite/demo? I'm working on linux but the library is portable so something cross platform would be greatly appreciated.